# Is removeWidget() necessary

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I just started with PyQt and I'm trying to sort elements in a `QGridLayout`. In the code below, I'm moving an existing button from the cell `(4,1)` to `(0,0)`. My confusion arises because either using `removeWidget` or not, both pieces of code behave exactly the same:

```
    myButton = self.myGridLayout.itemAtPosition(4, 1).widget()
    self.myGridLayout.removeWidget(myButton)
    self.myGridLayout.addWidget(myButton, 0, 0)
```

is the same as:

```
    myButton = self.myGridLayout.itemAtPosition(4, 1).widget()
    self.myGridLayout.addWidget(myButton, 0, 0)
```

Is PyQt handling everything behind the scenes or is there something that I have not noticed happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget can only belong to one layout. Before a widget is added to a layout, Qt will check to see if it has ever been in a layout, and if so, it will remove it from whatever layout it currently belongs to. The widget will also be automatically reparented to the layout's current parent-widget.

A widget also cannot be added to the same layout twice - but that is really no different from the case above, and so it is treated in exactly the same way.